# How can you selectively run ngBlur code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `textarea` and a `span`. The `textarea` has an `ngBlur` which calls a function. I only want that function to run its code when the cause of the blur wasn't a click on the span. How can I do that?

http://plnkr.co/edit/ENvuujbychxYum1EMmkf?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
    <textarea ng-blur='vm.selective()'></textarea>

    <span>span</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
;

function MainController() {
  vm.focus = true;

  vm.onBlur = function() {
    // HOW DO I DO THIS?
    // if (spanIsClicked) {
    //   return;
    // }

    vm.focus = false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can pass in the DOM element as an argument in angular, looking like :

```
vm.onBlur = function($event){}
```

You could then access the event by using ***event.target***. I know this works with ng-click so I'm not totally positive if the same rules apply for ng-blur.

Comment: You could do that with `ngBlur`, but the `event.target` is always the `textarea`; it doesn't tell you whether I clicked the `span`.